# Failed to upload coverage data. Reply by Coveralls: Build processing error for coveralls

Tags: r, travis-ci

I am passing following arguments:

```
after_success:
   - Rscript -e "covr::coveralls(repo_token= 'xxxx', service_name = 'travis-pro')"
```

However, it is throwing error as follows:
Failed to upload coverage data. Reply by Coveralls: Build processing error. I have ran following command, and i get result.

`z <- package_coverage()`. So, I don't know why it is failing.

When I run following command I get json, however, it contain whole file including Roxygen2 comments and function and also coverage information. I don't know if it is right or wrong.

Example:

```
xx = to_coveralls(coverage, repo_token = repo_token, service_name = service)
print(xx)
```

It return following json response:

> {"repo_token":"xxxxx","source_files":[{"name":"R/testFunct.R","source":"#'
>   @title Function for testFunct @param_id ... testFunct <- function(\n
>   param_id ...}

Any help is appreciated

Comment: https://github.com/r-lib/covr/pull/306/commits